# How to make std::optional a run-time monad with Hana?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, monads, option-type, boost-hana

The type [`hana::optional`](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1optional.html) represents an

> Optional value whose optional-ness is known at compile-time

and it models, among others, the concept of `Monad`. Since it is a compile-time optional, the question of what happens ***at run-time*** if I try to `hana::flatten` a non-empty `hana::optional` which ***doesn't*** wrap another `hana::optional` makes no sense, because because the error would be caught at compile-time.

But what about a run-time optional?

Here's my attempt on making `std::optional` (and only it, I'm not making a general concept of a maybe, which also `boost::optional` would satisfy) a `hana::Monad`, and I'd like to know if this is the correct way of doing it:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <boost/hana/chain.hpp>
#include <optional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_value_type : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct has_value_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T>
bool constexpr has_value_type_t = has_value_type<T>::value;

namespace boost::hana {

    template<typename T>
    struct transform_impl<std::optional<T>> {
        template <typename Opt, typename F>
        static constexpr auto apply(Opt&& o, F&& f) {
            return o.has_value() ? std::make_optional(f(o.value())) : std::nullopt;
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct flatten_impl<std::optional<T>> {
        template <typename X>
        static constexpr auto apply(X&& x) {
            if constexpr (has_value_type_t<typename X::value_type>)
                return (x.has_value() && x.value().has_value()) ? x.value() : std::nullopt;
            else {
                if (!x.has_value())
                    return std::nullopt;
                else
                    throw std::runtime_error("std::optional<non_stdoptional_type> can't be flattened!");
            }
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct flatten_impl<std::nullopt_t> {
        template <typename X>
        static constexpr auto apply(X&&) {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    };
}


int main() {
    assert(hana::flatten(std::optional<std::optional<int>>{3}) == std::optional<int>{3});
    assert(hana::flatten(std::optional<int>{}) == std::optional<int>{});
    assert(hana::flatten(std::nullopt) == std::optional<int>{});
    //assert(hana::flatten(std::optional<int>{2}) == std::optional<int>{}); // throws
}
```

Comment: Also you need a decay before colon colon

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, why shouldn't that line compile?

Comment: I was in error!  The decay is still needed.  With a forwarding reference, `X::value_type` isn't right if `X&&` is an lvalue.  `x.value().has_value()` is redundant, as `x` is already `nullopt` if it isn't true.  Also note that `optional<vector>` won't work, but maybe you don't care.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few improvements that can be made.

Boost.Hana uses a tag dispatch system for specializing the impl structs. This simplifies specialization, but also prevents a cartesian product of instantations of the outer impl struct with the inner function template.

Also your use of `value_type` to detect a nested optional is subject to error given the broad set of types that would satisfy this constraint. The tag system also helps with this if you use `hana::is_a<optional_tag, X>`.

This more specific constraint also eliminates your need to perform a run-time check for a nested optional since the information is in the type itself. `optional<optional<...>>`

Specializing for `flatten_impl<nullopt_t>` is incorrect since you can't run it through `transform`. I don't think it is necessary.

Here is a simplified version that also demonstrates you can transform the types.
It's also constexpr!

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <boost/hana/core/is_a.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/core/tag_of.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/flatten.hpp>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct my_optional_tag { };

namespace boost::hana {

    template <typename T>
    struct tag_of<std::optional<T>> {
        using type = my_optional_tag;
    };

    template <>
    struct transform_impl<my_optional_tag> {
        template <typename Opt, typename F>
        static constexpr auto apply(Opt&& o, F&& f) {
            using ResultValue = decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Opt>(o).value()));
            using Result = std::optional<std::decay_t<ResultValue>>;
            return o.has_value() ? Result(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Opt>(o).value())) :
                                   Result(std::nullopt);
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct flatten_impl<my_optional_tag> {
        template <typename X>
        static constexpr auto apply(X&& x) {
            using Nested = decltype(std::forward<X>(x).value());
            static_assert(is_a<my_optional_tag, Nested>, "must have nested optional");
            return std::forward<X>(x).value_or(Nested(std::nullopt));
        }
    };
}


int main() {
    // Functor
    static_assert(hana::transform(std::optional<int>{41}, [](int x) { return x + 1.0f; }) ==
            std::optional<float>{42});

    // Monad
    static_assert(hana::flatten(std::optional<std::optional<int>>{3}) == std::optional<int>{3});

    constexpr auto inc = [](int x) { return std::optional{x + 1.0f}; };
    static_assert(hana::chain(std::optional<int>{5}, inc) == std::optional{6.0f});

    static_assert(hana::flatten(std::optional<std::optional<int>>{std::nullopt}) == std::nullopt);

    // hana::flatten(std::optional<int>{3}); // compile-time error
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7KWGn6

Please note that I left out the implementations for `hana::lift` and `hana::ap` which are required for `hana::Applicative` which is required for `hana::Monad` (in the documented [minimal complete definition](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-_monad.html)). I will leave this to the reader.

Comment: Hi Jason. Would you spend another word on the second paragraph? Are you referring to the fact that the tag dispatch allows you to have `template<> struct some_impl<tag>` instead of `template<typename T> struct some_impl<something_of<T>>`? Is the cartesian product you mention the one between the type parameters of the template and the template paramter passed to the struct?

Comment: Furthermore, as regards the specialization for `nullopt_t`, how would you go about the parallel with Haskell's `(join Nothing == Nothing) == True`?

Comment: When you instantiate the impl template, the compiler has to rebuild and perform analysis on the member function template and its body. (granted nothing changes in this case so it might just have to walk the AST for the body). It would do this for every T which isn't necessary with the tag system.

Comment: You can still support `nullopt` if you want, but it must work with `transform` (with `lift` and `ap`) to satisfy `Functor` and `Applicative` which the `Monad` concept is not checking unfortunately. It is in the documentation however. I guess I left out the `Applicative` functions `lift` and `ap`.

Comment: `apply` doesn't handle the outer optional being nullopt?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Fixed. TY.  It still has to be a nested optional type though.

Comment: @JasonRice I think `Nested(std::nullopt)` can be replaced with `std::nullopt`.  You could also reduce it to `return x?std::forward<X>(x):std::nullopt;` usually.